# removeClass is overruled on click

Tags: jquery

I have a class that loads a modal box on click.

I want to remove this for a specific element so I'm using .removeClass

```
$('.future').removeClass('ajax-page-content');
```

Although the class is removed when viewing in the console, clicking the element still loads the modal box so it is overruled. How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: How do you bind click handler? You surely need to delegate it, e.g: `$(document).on('click', '.ajax-page-content', function(){...});`

Comment: FYI, you have to provide MCVE. You post code regarding `removeClass()` which you said works BUT didn't posted relevant code regarding your issue which is relevant to click event. `I bought green apples, why tomatoes are red?`

Comment: I've used this $('.ajax-page-content').on('click', function() {

});

Comment: So ya, delegate it, preferably to closest static container

Comment: so how would that look?

Comment: I posted one sample but this would give the idea: `$('.ajax-page-content').parent().on('click', '.ajax-page-content', function(){...});`. Now if you remove class, event won't be fired

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `on` method while registering on click listener like

```
$(document).on('click','.ajax-page-content',function(){
   console.log('clicked')
})
```

Comment: Ya because `selector` parameter of `on()` method is filtered on fired event. This is equivalent to: `$(document).on('click', function(event){ if(!$(event.target).is('.ajax-page-content')) return;
   console.log('clicked')
})`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the previously registered click event handler as well. You can use the jQuery [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method to do this.

```
yourJQuerySelectorForTheElement.unbind("click");
```

Assuming `yourJQuerySelectorForTheElement` is the element selected by jQuery. It is the element where you removed the `ajax-page-content` css class

This again depends on how you registered your click event. If you directly bound it to your elements using the click event handler, You need to explicitly remove it using the `unbind` method.

```
$(function(){

 $(".ajax-page-content").click(function(e){        
    alert("Show My modal popup");        
  });      

  $(document).on("click",".remove",function(e){
     var _this=$(this);

    _this.closest(".linkHolder") // This is just to get the parent div.
                                 // you may replace based on how you have your markup.

       .find("a.future")
       .removeClass("ajax-page-content")      
       .unbind("click");

  });      
});
```

Working sample on jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/livojomodi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

But if you have registered your click event handler using jquery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, you do not need to explicitly remove it.

```
$(document).on("click",".ajax-page-content",function(e){    
    alert("My modal popup");    
});
```

Working sample [here](http://jsbin.com/tocezozopa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)